# How does snapshotting with regards to Bane of the Stricken and health potions work?

Tags: diablo-iii

A lot of people have been talking about using your health potion at certain times to do something with Bane of the Stricken.

This is becoming increasingly more popular with the higher level greater rifts and I was wondering how this "snapshotting" functions regarding this legendary gem.

Comment: What class are you playing? I have a feeling this has more to do with some talents that Increase damage when below X% of health than the gem itself since the gem does not have any health related benefits.

Comment: I am playing DH in Season 4, but I've heard most of the higher level greater rift Monks are using this technique.

Comment: This looks like a tactic to use with the [esoteric alteration legend gem](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/esoteric-alteration), doubt that Bane of the stricken is needed for that but since everyone use it in S4...

Comment: Regular health potions, not legendary bottomless potions?

Comment: I think it's any legendary potion or a regular health potion. I'm not 100% sure though, hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how it works -

Bane of the Stricken has in Internal CoolDown, which means that the proc ability from BotS does not apply with every hit, it applies when the hit and the ICD align to allow a proc.

So if your attack speed is hyper fast, the ICD of BotS will not match your attacks, meaning that you can hit 3 times in 1 second, not all 3 hits will apply the BotS proc.

It turns out that BotS ICD is snapshotted whenever you enter a zone, use a health potion, or revive.

Also, what this means is that the higher your attack speed is, the faster the ICD will expire.

In turn, most things that raise your attack speed while you are fighting, will not go towards the ICD of BotS, that is, until you use a health potion, in which case BotS will re-snapshot it's ICD based on your current attack speed.

Read [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/3k30ej/an_indepth_guide_to_bane_of_the_stricken/) for more in-depth explanation.

Comment: To make it a bit clearer: the ICD **does** scale with character's Attack Speed, but not immediately. It needs to be manually updated with changing zones or using a potion.